# Facebook user data is empty when inserted into Mysql db

Tags: php, mysql, facebook

I'v currently developing a php facebook canvas in an IFrame. The Idea is for the user to upload pictures to mySql Database with the userdata supplied by Facebook from there api.

Everything goes well until I have to save the Userdata along with picture. After I pushed submit and the picture is uploaded. it reloads the page and the picture is shown, but the userdata from facebook is not inserted along with it. I have tried lots of options here on the internet but it doesn't care.. It will not inser the userdata along with the picture.

I have an index file which looks like this:

```
        <?php 
    setcookie("fag");
    session_start();
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <title>Facebook</title>
    <?php
    define('MyConst', TRUE);
    include_once 'ClassLibrary/User_AR.php';
    include_once 'ClassLibrary/FacebookApi.php';
    include_once 'ClassLibrary/ImageUpload.php';
    $sr = new User_AR();
    $fb = new FacebookApi();
    $iu = new ImageUpload();
                $info = $fb->getUserInfo();
                $_COOKIE["fag"] = $info;
                    foreach ($info as $key => $v )
            {
            switch ($key)
            {
            case "ID":
                echo $v;
                break;
            case "Name":

                echo $v;
                break;
            case "Email":
                echo    $v;
                break;
            case "Img":
                echo $v;

                break;
            }
            }
    ?>

    </head>

    <body>

    <?php 

             if (isset($_POST["sendPhoto"])) {
                echo "Is Set";

                if ($sr->exists($info["ID"]) == false) {
             $iu->processForm();
                }else{
                $iu->displayForm();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $iu->displayForm();
                echo "Is not Set";
            }
    $arr = array($sr->getAllUsers());
     for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++){
    foreach ($arr[$i] as $key => $value) {
            echo "<div class=".'"'."userBox".'"'.">"."<div class=".'"'."innerBox".'"'.">
            <div class=".'"'."Title".'"'.">Navn :</div><div class=".'"'."Values".'"'.">".$value["Name"]."</div>".
            "<div class=".'"'."Dato".'"'.">Dato :</div><div class=".'"'."Values".'"'.">".date("m.d.y")."</div>".
            "<div class=".'"'."Title".'"'.">Billede :</div><div class=".'"'."img".'"'."><img alt=".'"'."BrugerBillede".'"'." height=".'"'."150".'"'." width=".'"'."150".'"'." class=".'"'."Image".'"'."src=".'"'.$value["Img"].'"'."/></div></div></div>";
         }
     }

    ?>



    </body>
    </html>
```

Keep in mind that this code is sandbox code and may contain odd words that is the result of a tired developer who can't get this to work!

Anyway this is supposed to show the uploadform and let you upload the file and if you are registeret in the mysql db it wont show you the form.

Now this is the ImageUpload file which contains the code for upload picture getting the information.

```
function __construct()
{       
        $killer = $_COOKIE["fag"];

            foreach ($killer as $key => $v )
            {
        switch ($key)
        {
        case "ID":
            $id = $v;
            echo $id;
            break;
        case "Name":
            $name = $v;
            echo $name;
            break;
        case "Email":
            $email = $v;
            echo $email;
            break;
        case "Img":
            $img = $v;
            echo $img;
            break;
            }

        }

}

    function displayForm() {

    echo "<form action=".'"'.$this->processForm().'"'. "method=".'"'."post".'"'."enctype=".'"'."multipart/form-data".'"'.">
<div>

<input type=".'"'."hidden".'"'. "name=".'"'."MAX_FILE_SIZE".'"'."value=".'"'."100000".'"'."/>
<label for=".'"'."userfile".'"'.">Upload file:</label>
<input type=".'"'."file".'"'."name=".'"'."photo".'"'. "id=".'"'."photo".'"'."/>
<input type=".'"'."submit".'"'. "name=".'"'."sendPhoto".'"'."value=".'"'."Send Photo".'"'."/>

</div>
</form>";
    }
function processForm(){
    $se = new User_AR();
            if (isset($_FILES["photo"]) && $_FILES["photo"]["error"] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK){

                if ($_FILES["photo"]["type"] !="image/jpeg") {
                        echo "<p>Kun JPG or PNG </p>";
                        $this->bool = false;
                }
                else if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"], "images/".basename($_FILES["photo"]["name"])))
                {
                    //echo "<p>Im sorry there was a problem uploading that photo</p>".$_FILES["photo"]["error"];
                }
                else 
                {



                $se->InsertPict($this->name,$this->email,"images/".basename($_FILES["photo"]["name"]),$this->id);           
                $this->displayThanks();         

                }

            }else{

            echo $_FILES["photo"]["error"];
            }



/*              if (isset($_FILES["photo"])&& $_FILES["photo"]["error"] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
            if ($_FILES["photo"]["type"] !="image/jpeg") {
                echo "<p>Kun JPG </p>";

            }else if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"], "images/".basename($_FILES["photo"]["name"])))
            {
                echo "<p>Im sorry there was a problem uploading that photo</p>".$_FILES["photo"]["error"];

            }else{

                }
        }else 
        {
            switch ($_FILES["photo"]["error"]) {
                case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
                    $message = "The photo is larger than server allows";
                    break;
                case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:  
                    $message = "The photo is larger  than the script allows.";
                break;
                case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:
                    $message = "No file was uploaded. Make sure you choose a file to upload.";

                default:
                    $message = "Please contact your server administrator for help";
                break;
            }
    echo "FEST          ". $killer["Name"];
        }*/
            function getitman() {


            }

    }

    function displayThanks() {
        echo "<p><img src=".'"'."images/".$_FILES["photo"]["name"].'"'." alt=".'"'."Photo".'"'."/> Thanks!</p>";
    }

    function __destruct() {

    }
}

?>
```

Now this is where it gets totally weird and crazy. this line of code it wont do what i tell it to do (only save the image)

```
$se->InsertPict($this->name,$this->email,"images/".basename($_FILES["photo"]["name"]),$this->id);
```

When put it this if/else construction it will only save my image NOT the userdata

```
function processForm(){
    $se = new User_AR();
            if (isset($_FILES["photo"]) && $_FILES["photo"]["error"] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK){

                if ($_FILES["photo"]["type"] !="image/jpeg") {
                        echo "<p>Kun JPG or PNG </p>";
                        $this->bool = false;
                }
                else if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"], "images/".basename($_FILES["photo"]["name"])))
                {
                    //echo "<p>Im sorry there was a problem uploading that photo</p>".$_FILES["photo"]["error"];
                }
                else 
                {
                $se->InsertPict($this->name,$this->email,"images/".basename($_FILES["photo"]["name"]),$this->id);           
                $this->displayThanks();         

                }

            }else{

            echo $_FILES["photo"]["error"];
            }





}
```

But as soon as I put it outside of the if/else construct it saves all the information.. but not the image and does this as soon as I connect to the facebook ap/canvas page. which is not desirable (since users has to upload picture). But I am so confused and about to go stark raving mad because of this crazy code!

This is the User_AR php file:

```
<?php
include_once 'ClassLibrary/DbConn.php';
include_once 'ClassLibrary/FacebookApi.php';

class User_AR  {

    function getAllUsers() {
    $exp = array();
    $con = new DbConn();
    $result =  $con->command("select * FROM User");
    while (($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))!=false) {
        $exp[] = array("ID" => $row["UserID"],"Name" => $row["UserName"],"Email" =>$row["UserEmail"],"Img" => $row["UserImg"],"FaceID" => $row["UserFaceID"]);
}
    return $exp;
    }

public  function InsertPict($Name,$Email,$Img,$ID) {
        $con = new DbConn();
        if (mysqli_num_rows($con->command("SELECT * FROM User WHERE UserFaceID =".$ID.""))== 0) {
            $res = $con->command("INSERT INTO User(UserName, UserEmail,UserImg, UserFaceID) values('$Name','$Email','$Img','$ID')");
        echo    $message = "Dit billede er nu lagt op og du deltager i konkurrencen";
        }else 
        {
        echo    $message = "Du har allerede indsendt et billede og deltager i konkurrencen";

        }

    }
    function exists($faceID) {
        $fb = new FacebookApi();
        $gg = $fb->getUserInfo();

//$game  = count_chars($_COOKIE["fag"]["Name"],3);
///     echo $game.$gg["Name"];
        $con = new DbConn();
        if (mysqli_num_rows($con->command("SELECT * FROM User WHERE UserFaceID = $faceID")) == 0) {
            $var = false;

            return $var;
        }else 
        {
            $var = true;
            return $var;
        }
    }


}

?>
```

I know this to work, because when I move the function "InsertPict" outside of the if/else in the ImageUpload class it works perfectly.

Since I'v been at this for aeons and maybe blind to obvious mistakes or such.. Can any of you fellow dev. help me out here before I go completely nuts and get fired for eating the keyboard. I will gladly appriciate any help.

Thanks on beforehand!

Comment: tl;dr.  Can you narrow down the code to where you think the problem is?

Comment: sho thats a lot to go through

Comment: The problem is when I try implement the function/method function processForm(). if I place $se->InsertPict() inside the "else" construct or the if construct I simply won't take any of the Facebook userdata variables with it. It only inserts "nothing" in MySQl even though it's not allowed to be empty. I tried to make an count on the $_cookie["fag"] and it say's 4 which is the correct amount of elements in it. If I take it out of the "if/else" construct it works nicely but without any image and it initiat as soon as I land on the site (not good).  I just dont get it! it's so weird!

Comment: So basically there seems to be nothing wrong with method InsertPict() or the way i get the FB info. I think there is something wrong with my processForm() method or the way I use processForm() in my Index.php file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up rewritting the entire code and that solved the problem. Instead of using the example code given on the facebook dev. page i used the php base code files and that worked.  Sorry for the inconvinience.